# How do we make a child instance not equal to its parent instance?

Tags: java, parent-child

For example, if I have a Person **parent** class and a Student extends Person **child** class, is there a way to implement the *equals()* or *hashCode()* functions where their instances would not be equal to each other?

Let's say Person class has fields name and age.
Student class has field grade and the following constructor:

```
public Student(String name, int age, int grade) {
super(name, age);
this.grade = grade;
}
```

How can I make two such instances where they have matching fields but if one is an instance of Person and the other is an instance of Student, it would return false?

```
Person student1 = new Student("John", 14, 8);
Student student2 = new Student("John" 14, 8);
```

Is it possible to make student1.equals(student2) return false?

Comment: You have two Student instances in your example. And student1.equals(student2) will be false if you simple omit equals implementation

Comment: *Is it possible to make student1.equals(student2) return false?* - why do you need that?

Comment: It is not possible for a `Person` instance to have the same field values as a `Student` instance, because `Student` has an extra field which `Parent` doesn't have.

Comment: IRL students generally have a unique ID.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you really want that any 2 instances of `Student` are always different (for this you can simply not override `equals()` method, which would basically compare the object references and not the content itself), this does not make sense.

Assigning `new Student("John", 14, 8)` to a `Person` or `Student` variable does not make it different between them. The object is exactly the same in terms of content (they are indeed two different objects). You are just referring to them using different classes.